# MySQL Set all values of the column value to be 0 exept id 4

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to set all values of the column value to be 0 except id 4. Is it possible to do this in one query?

I want something like this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET value = 0 
WHERE id != 4 and SET value = 1 WHERE id = 4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value equal to `id = 4` which is a Boolean expression that evaluates to `1` if it is `true` or `0` if it is `false`:

```
UPDATE table SET value = (id = 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression:

```
update mytable
set value = case id when 4 then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use if statement as well. If id = 4 is true then set value = 1 else set value = 0. Hope this may help you.

```
Update table set value = if(id=4, 1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table  SET (value = 0 WHERE id != 4 ),(value = 1 WHERE id = 4)

Comment: At least your previous (now deleted answer) contained valid sql code. Your current code is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Also, there is no need to delete an answer and post a new one. Just click on edit at the bottom of your answer and make any changes that you want.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To check if your SQL code, you can try to use online websites, like this one: https://en.rakko.tools/tools/36/

(Then fix your question with the `Edit` command